# Bijective simplicial mapping which is not homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I'm looking for such bijective simplicial mapping $f:S_0 \to T_0$ that $|f|:|S| \to |T|$ is not homeomorphism. $S_0$ and $T_0$ are set of vertices of simplexes. I know that it is enough, that $f^{-1}$ is not simplicial mapping, but can't find example.

Comment: Do you mean something like ∴ → △?

Comment: This will work whenever you start with a simplicial complex $S$ and you add a face to it to obtain $S'$. Then the identity $S_0\to S_0'$ is what you are looking for.